# Scanner error that I can't figure out: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

It's crashing on the third line inside the do-while loop, and doesn't wait for my input:

```
 input = kb.nextInt();
```

Stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>
> at main.MainDriver.main(MainDriver.java:50)

Relevant code:

```
do
    {
        displayFullMenu();
        System.out.print("Selection: ");
        input = kb.nextInt();
        
        switch (input)
        {
        //Create new survey
        case 1:     currentSurvey = new Survey();
                    break;
        
        //Display current survey            
        case 2:     currentSurvey.display();
                    break;
        
        //Save current survey           
        case 3:     saveSurvey(currentSurvey);
                    break;
                    
        //Load a survey
        case 4:     currentSurvey = loadSurvey();
                    break;
        
        //Modify a survey
        case 5:     currentSurvey.modify();
                    break;
                    
        /*******************Test Functions*******************/
                    
        //Create new test
        case 6:     currentSurvey = new Test();
                    break;
        
        //Display current test
        case 7:     currentSurvey.display();
                    break;
        
        //Save current test
        case 8:     saveSurvey(currentSurvey);
                    break;
                    
        //Load a test
        case 9:     currentSurvey = loadTest();
                    break;
                    
        //Modify a test
        case 10:    currentSurvey.modify();
                    
        default:    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please make a valid choice: ");
                    input = kb.nextInt();
                    System.out.println();
        }
    } while (input != 99);
    kb.close();
```

It crashes after I choose option 9. It saves the file correctly, then goes back to the top of the loop, and crashes at the previously mentioned line. I want it to ask for more input.

What gives?

Comment: How are you initializing your scanner. Are you using "Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);" ?  Also, enabling debugging symbols when you compile will give you line numbers in your stack trace.

Comment: @djsumdog yes I am initializing it that way. When I choose option 8, in saveSurvey(), it has to create a new Scanner (in that method) because all of this is inside my main method. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Is that the only place where your instantiating the Scanner and closing it? May be you you are doing the same in some of those methods being called there.

Comment: @Bhest Gurung that's correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I choose option 8, in `saveSurvey()`, it has to create a new Scanner (in that method) because all of this is inside my main method. Could that be the issue?

Yes, that could be the issue. If that `Scanner` has the same source (`System.in`?) as `kb` and is `close()`d, that closes the underlying stream, and `kb` cannot get input anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I detailed this more in my answer. This was it.

Comment: +1. Thank you! Just encountered the same issue. I was doing `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)` in some method, that I called multiple times, and `scanner.close()` before returning from the method. So after the first call, I just **closed** the underlying stream. Shame )

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The whole issue was caused by me not creating a static scanner in main - and when I needed it in other methods outside of main, I created new ones.

Instead of

```
public class MainDriver
{
    public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
   {
```

I had:

```
public class MainDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And then created new scanners in the other methods. At the end of those methods, I closed the Scanner. I guess it was closing the local scanner, because when I got rid of all `close()` statements that were inside the other methods, the issue disappeared.