# This message keeps appearing "java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayBox2 {

```
public static void box (int length, int width){ 

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    String Answer; 

    System.out.println("Do you want to use a special character to use to display the box ?"); 
      Answer = input.nextLine();

    if (Answer == "Yes"){
        System.out.println("Please enter the character that you would like to display the box");
        int Char = input.nextInt(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                System.out.print(Char +" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    if (Answer == "No"){

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }


    input.close(); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);  

    int length, width ; 

    System.out.println ("Please enter the length of the box"); 
    length = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println (" Please enter the width of the box");
    width = input.nextInt(); 

    input.close(); 


    box (length, width); 


}
```

}

i dont understand what the error is in my code. can anyone please help

Please enter the length of the box

5
 Please enter the width of the box

5
Do you want to use a special character to use to display the box ?

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

```
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)

at methods.DisplayBox2.box(DisplayBox2.java:14)

at methods.DisplayBox2.main(DisplayBox2.java:56)
```

Comment: Answer = input.nextLine(); // this is line 14

Comment: box (length, width);  //this is line 56

Comment: Then also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @YassinHH You need to have the privilege (it'll appear next to the `edit` button, which you gain when reaching a certain amount of reputation. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: What is close @YassinHH

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can not help you because I don't have enough reputation apparently lol.

Comment: @elliot Nooo, that's what I closed as to start, but they're asking about the Scanner throwing NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ooh. Then it's a dupe about the `input.close(); `; like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042139/java-tryscanner-scan-new-scannersystem-in-causing-an-exception).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was thinking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input) one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223723/scanner-error-that-i-cant-figure-out-nosuchelementexception). Popular question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

package methods;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayBox2 {

```
public static void box (int length, int width, String character){ 

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                System.out.print(character +" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }





public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);  

    int length, width ; 
    String Answer; 
    String character = ""; 

    System.out.println("Do you want to use a special character to use to display the box ?"); 
      Answer = input.next();

  if (Answer.equals("Yes")){
    System.out.println("Please enter the character that you would like to display the box");
     character =  input.next();
  }

  if (Answer == "No"){
      character = "*"; 
  }
    System.out.println ("Please enter the length of the box"); 
    length = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println (" Please enter the width of the box");
    width = input.nextInt(); 

    input.close(); 


    box (length, width, character); 


}
}
```

My answer.I didn't use try catch and finally but it works so its good.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected the code for you to work:

```
public static void box(int length, int width, Scanner input) {

        String answer;

        System.out.println("Do you want to use a special character to use to display the box ?");
        answer = input.next();
        if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the character that you would like to display the box");
            int Char = input.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    System.out.print(Char + " ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }else if (answer.equals("No")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" *");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            int length, width;
            System.out.println("Please enter the length of the box");
            length = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(" Please enter the width of the box");
            width = input.nextInt();

            box(length, width, input);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

**Points to note:**

- When you use `input.close()`, you are closing the `System.in` and not the Scanner and hence you are getting `NoSuchElementException`
- Compare String only with `equals()` - compares values, other than `'=='` that compares references. It's a basic but common mistake for learners
- Use `try/catch/finally` and especially `finally` to close/clean resources. If you use JDK 1.7 or higher, try with resources can help much better

Comment: Thanks man ! We didn't learn try/catch/finally yet although we do use JDK1.7 so i guess we learn about it in the future

Comment: @ArbaazShakeel Cool. Please close the thread by marking the answer if you think its resolved. Keep learning.. :)

Comment: @ArbaazShakeel What's that? any issues?

Comment: nvm that was a mistake

Comment: You can use try and finally alone. catch is optional. finally ensures that the code blocks in finally is executed even if there are exceptions. So, you safely close it at any case. However there are cases when finally won't execute. I will leave it to you to read. cheers.